# Increase the stroke-width of a polygon in Mapbox Studio

Tags: mapbox

Apparently, the "stroke-width" property is fixed at 1px and cannot be changed. Are there any workarounds?

Comment: Does this limitation also apply to setting the border to 0px?

Answer (score 11):

The 1px stroke-width is a limitation of WebGL as explained in this [issue comment](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/3018#issuecomment-240381965). The workaround is to set the data type as `line` instead of `fill` under the `Select data` tab of the layer editor. You can then set the stroke of the polygon.

If you wish to have both fill and stroke (of greater than 1px), you need to add two separate layers to achieve this.

Comment: @jay I can't see a way to change the stroke to a width of 0px - is this supported? It doesn't appear so and I'm trying to remove my borders, but I can't seem to find a way to do it. Seems related, though I can post a new question if needed.

Comment: @SqlRyan If you are using a fill type, your border should match the the color of your fill so shouldn't be visible, unless you're using an RGBA color for the `fill-color` property (the stroke will ignore the alpha property of that color). If this is the case, use an RGB color for `fill-color` and set the opacity via `fill-opacity` so both your fill and stroke are the same.